# Update all occurrences of a datetime to the lowest datetime value for that date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, aggregate-functions

I have a table with many datetime values for many dates. I need to update my table so that each date is updated to the lowest datetime value for that date. For example, if this is my table:

```
Station     DateTime
Stn 1   2014-03-26 09:50:00.000
Stn 1   2014-03-26 09:52:00.000
Stn 1   2014-03-26 09:55:00.000
Stn 2   2015-12-26 11:30:00.000
Stn 2   2015-12-26 11:32:00.000
Stn 2   2015-12-26 11:35:00.000
```

I need to update the datetime field to look like this:

```
Station     DateTime
Stn 1   2014-03-26 09:50:00.000
Stn 1   2014-03-26 09:50:00.000
Stn 1   2014-03-26 09:50:00.000
Stn 2   2015-12-26 11:30:00.000
Stn 2   2015-12-26 11:30:00.000
Stn 2   2015-12-26 11:30:00.000
```

For each station, I need to make all of the datetime values equal to the minimum datetime value for that station. I've been playing with aggregate functions now for over an hour, but I can't seem to get it. I've tried looking for help online, but this is a hard question to phrase in a search engine.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MIN()` window function in a CTE to get the lowest value of `Time` for each combination of Station and date.
In the `UPDATE` statement join the table to the CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, MIN(Time) OVER (PARTITION BY Station, CONVERT(DATE, Time)) min_time
  FROM tablename
)
UPDATE t
SET t.Time = c.min_time
FROM tablename t INNER JOIN cte c 
ON c.Station = t.Station AND c.Time = t.Time;
```

Comment: That CTE is updatable directly, no need to join on the table again.

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server, you can use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             min(time) over (partition station, convert(date, time)) as min_time
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set time = min_time
    where time <> min_time;
```

Note that no `join` is needed and the `where` clause prevents unnecessary updates.